# Bizarre Contract Violation in Judgment

Tags: racket, contract, redex

I have a `judgement` with the following contract:

```
(define-judgment-form DynamicLam
  #:mode     (down I I O O)
  #:contract (down Γ e Γ e)

  [----------------"Lambda"
   (down Γ_0 z_0 Γ_0 z_0)]
  ;; rest of the code ...
)
```

When I run this:

```
(define empty (term ()))
(redex-match? DynamicLam Γ empty)
(redex-match? DynamicLam e lam1^*)
(redex-match? DynamicLam z lam1^*)
(judgment-holds (down empty lam1^* empty lam1^*))
```

I get back:

> #t
>
> #t
>
> #t
>
> . . down: judgment input values do not match its contract;
>   (unknown output values indicated by _)
>    contract: (down Γ e Γ e)
>    values:   (down empty lam1^* _ _)

But this does not make sense, because I clearly used `redex-match?` above to test:

- That `empty` matches `Γ`
- That `lam1^*` matches `e`
- And furthermore that `lam1^*` matches `z`.

What am I missing?  Is there more to the meaning of `#:contract` than just matching `Γ e Γ e`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the `#:mode` to `(down I I I I)` instead of `(down I I O O)`, and changing

```
(judgment-holds (down empty lam1^* empty lam1^*))
```

to

```
(judgment-holds (down ,empty ,lam1^* ,empty ,lam1^*))
```

The `,` change makes a lot of sense to me but I still do not understand why the two outputs needed to be inputs, so if someone can either edit this answer to explain that, or provide a comment or another answer explaining that subtlety, that would be fantastic.